# NHibernate does not update Index-column when removing an object from a list

Tags: nhibernate

My class A has a property:

```
public virtual IList<IVisitor> Visitors { get; set; }
```

which is mapped as follows:

```
<list name="Visitors" table="Visitor" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="SomeID" not-null="true" update="false" />
  <index column="idx" />
  <one-to-many class="Visitor" />
</list>
```

When there are 3 objects in the list, they have the idx 0, 1, and 2.

Now when I remove the middle object and save my instance of A like:

```
a.Visitors.RemoveAt( 1 );
a.Save(); // calls session.SaveOrUpdate( a );
```

the appropriate row is deleted but the other two rows keep its idx 0 and 2.

Why is NHibernate not updating it to 0 and 1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are not updated because your mapping mandates them not to be updated.

Remove `update="false"` from your `key` mapping. It does apply to `index` too. The index is considered part of the list key.

If you use an old version of NHibernate, you may additionally have this [old bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-298).

Comment: It seems to work, thanks! I just copied the update="false" from another list where I needed it, forgot why though. All tests are green so it might have no impact

Comment: Maybe because of [this](/a/11576097/1178314).